# NSTextfield complete

Tags: cocoa, autocomplete, nstextfield

It is there a solution to have a completion of a NSTextField with method :

```
- (NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(int*)index
```

with several words and not one? Because when you type a space, the completion start again...

Thanks.

Comment: really sorry, I did not know this manipulation

Answer (score 4):

Better late than never, it might be helpful for others:

It's a little tricky problem, since `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` / `NSTextFieldDelegate` doesn't offer a way to solve it directly. What you need to do is creating a custom subclass of `NSTextView` (yes, text **view**), and override the method `- (NSRange)rangeForUserCompletion`:

```
- (NSRange)rangeForUserCompletion
{
    return [self selectedRange];
}
```

And then subclass `NSTextFieldCell` to override the method `- (NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:`:

```
- (NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)aControlView
{
    static MyTextView* _myFieldEditor = nil;
    if (_myFieldEditor == nil) {
        _myFieldEditor = [[MyTextView alloc] init];
        [_myFieldEditor setFieldEditor:YES];
    }
    return _myFieldEditor;
}
```

Then in Interface Builder, set the class of your text field's cell to your subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`. What will happen is when your text field becomes first responder, the window will call your cell's `-fieldEditorForView:` method, and use your custom text view as the **field editor**. So during editing the value of your text field, any completion will call `-(NSRange)rangeForUserCompletion` on your text view.

Then you can fine tune your `-rangeForUserCompletion` to make it return the exact range you want for the completion.

Also, the code in `fieldEditorForView:` assumes that your app uses **only one window**, if you are using multiple windows (e.g. document-based apps), you'll have to change it and keep **one field editor instance per window**.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, been trying to work this out for a while. For information the following can be used to fine tune -rangeForUserCompletion to allow multiple words

    NSRange range = [super rangeForUserCompletion];
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = [[self string] length];
    return range;